# Array created using dayjs outputs undefined elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I am trying to make a react calendar using dayJs library, I create a 2d array for month using the following code :

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export const getMonth = (month = dayjs().month()) => {
    const year = dayjs().year();
    const firstDayOfMonth = dayjs(new Date(year, month, 1)).day();
    let currentMonthCount = 0 - firstDayOfMonth;
    const daysMatrix = new Array(5).fill([]).map(() => {
        return new Array(7).fill(null).map(() => {
            currentMonthCount++
            return dayjs(new Date(year, month, currentMonthCount))
        })
    });
    return daysMatrix;
};
```

now when I import the function in my app.js file and pass it onto another component `month.js` which displays the array using the following code :

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Day from '../components/Day';

const Month = ({ month }) => {
  if(month) {
    month.map((e) => console.log(e));
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex-1 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5'>
      {month.map((row, i) => (
        <Fragment key={i}>
          {row.map((day, j) => (
            <Day day={day} key={j} />
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};
export default Month;
```

here, the console log outputs the month array as it should but I get an error in the return section stating `unable to read properties of undefined reading map`, could someone please explain why am I getting this error although the map worked fine for the console.log statement?

my app.js file :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getMonth } from './util';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import CalendarHeader from './components/CalendarHeader';
import Sidebar from './components/Month';
import Month from './components/Month';

function App() {
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(getMonth());
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='h-screen flex flex-col' >
        <CalendarHeader />
        <div className="flex flex-1">
          <Sidebar />
          <Month month={currentMonth} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: promise error without a promise being used in a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614481/angular-promise-error-without-a-promise-being-used-in-a-subscription)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unable to read properties of undefined reading map` this kind of error can occur when you are trying to loop over or using the `map` method over an undefined value.
To resolve this you can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#try_it).

In your case, you need to use this in `Month` component as done below:

```
{month?.map((row, i) => (
        <Fragment key={i}>
          {row?.map((day, j) => (
            <Day day={day} key={j} />
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
```

Let me know if this works for you.